# Uploading file with express

Tags: node.js, file-upload, express

I am trying to make a simple file server able to save a file using express:

```
var app = express();
app.use(express.bodyParser({uploadDir:'./uploads'}))
app.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Uploading File");

    req.on('data', function(raw) {
        console.log('received data: ' + raw);
    });

    req.on('end', function() {
        console.log('File uploaded');
        res.send(200);
    });

});
```

I am only getting a empty file in "uploads" folder.

What am I missing?

Maybe is a really silly question but I am new with node.js.

**Edit**: More information...

I am sending this from my client:

```
POST /upload HTTP/1.1
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 42
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="MIME_boundary_572B1A2B457D3267"
Cookie: session.id=b268b12e-0c05-11e3-8702-7a7919510927
Host: localhost:8080
Transfer-Encoding: chunked


Client 3 Received Message: E4
--MIME_boundary_572B1A2B457D3267
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test1.txt"; filename="test1.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

File1 from client in W7 to send to server.
--MIME_boundary_572B1A2B457D3267--

0
```

In two chuncks.

Comment: Is this link helpful? http://howtonode.org/really-simple-file-uploads

Comment: I read that and does not for me.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to `> getting an empty file in "uploads" folder`,

You must save the (decoded) request body to a file.

Also note that the client content encoding is **multipart**. Resembling the **multipart** content is tricky. You can use **bodyParser** middleware for that.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15773267/303270) answer for more info.

Comment: I understand your answer but I am not able to get the second "chunk" to get hte file content

Comment: it's important the attribute enctype in the html <form> is set to multipart, with :   
     enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: +1 for the answer but was a problem with my client. I checked the server with a simple http form and works fine.