# Display images from multipart/form-data parsers without saving

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multipartform-data, formidable

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15773267/4451066), images uploaded through multipart/form-data parsers are saved in a temp folder `const tempPath = req.file.path`. Then they are copied to a specified directory `const targetPath = path.join(__dirname, "./uploads/image.png");` Those images then can be displayed like `<img src="/uploads/image.png" />`

I understand that browser cannot display an image in system's temp folder. Is there another way to display images without copying them like above? Can I convert `req.file` to be displayed in `<img />`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display the image on the client side without send the image to the server side by listening to the onChange event of the input with the file type. This is how I do with ReactJS ([Demo on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zrw47vmjlm))

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = { imageSrc: '' };

    onImageChange = (event) => {
        if(event.target.files.length !== 0) {
            const reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (e) => {
            this.setState({ imageSrc: e.target.result });
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
    }
 }

  render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <input type="file" accept="image/*" onChange={this.onImageChange} />
                {this.state.imageSrc ? <img src={this.state.imageSrc} /> : null}
            </div>
        );
   }
}
```

Hope it helps. Let me know if I misuderstand your question

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in python/Flask, I am sure you can adapt it to other languages

this is your image file inside the request on the server:

```
uploaded_file = request.files.get('image')
```

in Flask you can display it back to the user without saving as follows:

```
return "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64, " + base64.b64encode(uploaded_file.read()).decode('ascii') + "'>"
```