# How can i blog component in Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack, web-deployment

I want to make a blog component in Angular with Nodejs as backend,
the blog structure contains : Image and Description and i want to upload it in a single event to the backend(nodejs and mongodb).

The main concern is how to upload image and its description together in a single event to the backend.

Comment: The same way you send data from any form in Angular, you use a model to track it?

Comment: But I want to send a image with form data and want to use multer but this is not happening with single request

Comment: this will help you [post-form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772394/how-to-upload-display-and-save-images-using-node-js-and-express)

Comment: @MuhammadShareyar but i also want to send some text data like captions with the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example.

```
<form
  [formGroup]="angForm" novalidate (submit)="createBlog(angForm)" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="form-group">
     <textarea class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Create a post" formControlName="data" #data  ></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <inpu type="file" name="image" name="image" #image (change)="onFileSelect($event)"/>
   </div>
   <button type="submit class="btn btn-dark" [disabled]="angForm.pristine || angForm.invalid" > Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Here is a simple `angular reactive form` we use to validate the fields that are required and we defined `onFileSelect()` function on change input value that we will use to save `formData`

blog.ts file

```
 import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

 angForm: FormGroup;

 //our constructor 
 constructor(
   private fb: FormBuilder,
   private http: HttpClient
  ) {
      this.createForm();
    }

 //reactive form group and set validations for required field
 createForm() {
   this.angForm = this.fb.group({
   data: [null, Validators.required],
   image: [""]
  });
 }

 createBlog(form) {
 const formData = new FormData();
 formData.append("image", this.angForm.get("image").value);
 formData.append("data", this.angForm.get("data").value);

 this.http
   .post("http://localhost:3000/blog/create", formData)
   .subscribe(res => {
     console.log(res);
   });
 }

  //on change event we append file to formdata
  onFileSelect(event) {
   if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
   const file = event.target.files[0];
   this.angForm.get("image").setValue(file);
  }
 }
```

To save files in nodejs you need to use `multer` package, and body-Parser to save text data

```
 const multer = require("multer");
 const upload = multer({ dest: "public/images/" }); //desired path to save file
//your post route to save data
router.post( "/create",upload.single("file"),(req, res) => { 
 if (req.file) {
     //creating instance of new blog 
      const newBlog = new Blog({
      desc: req.body.data,
      image: req.file.filename
    });

    //save blog data and image name into db
    newBlog.save().then(blog => {
       res.json(blog);
     // return response 
    });
   } else throw "error";
  }       
);
```

Comment: Can you just provide me a link to this code. P.S this.createForm() in the constructor is also giving a error

Comment: FormData() is not appending multiple files @MuhammadShareyar

Comment: For multiple files you need to name it is as array in your form like `name=image[]`

Comment: And even the set value on file is giving error : **Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.**

Comment: when i am selecting the file

Comment: Did you add `multiple` attribute in your `input` tag `<input type="file" name="image" name="image" #image (change)="onFileSelect($event)" multiple />` do this and check it will work fine then @ShivaChandel

Comment: It didnt worked and stilll giving the same error as mentioned above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192702/discussion-between-muhammad-shareyar-and-shiva-chandel).