# How to upload captured photo (from browser - canvas) to node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I want to upload the captured photo in canvas from browser in javascript to nodejs server. I am not getting a proper method. Please help. Thank you so much.

```
(function(){
  var video=document.getElementById('video'), 
  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
  context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  //photo = document.getElementById('photo');
  navigator.getMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                       navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                       navigator.msGetUserMedia;
  navigator.getMedia({
       video: true,
       audio: false
  }, function(stream){
      video.srcObject=stream;
      video.play();
  }, function(error){

  });
  document.getElementById('capture').addEventListener('click',function(){
        context.drawImage(video,0,0,400,300);
    //    photo.setAttribute('src',canvas.toDataURL('image/png')); 
       download();
   });
})();
function download() {
var download = document.getElementById("capture");
var image = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png")
    .replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
download.setAttribute("href", image);
//download.setAttribute("download","archive.png");
}
```

This code works fine to download a captured image but I am not getting a way to upload same image to node server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload, display and save images using node.js and express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772394/how-to-upload-display-and-save-images-using-node-js-and-express)

Comment: @rebecca It's a bit different, Sneha wants to get the data from a canvas, and send that data (without the upload button, I reckon)

Comment: ah, well you're right, sorry. 
but: @Sneha i think you could create an empty [Formdata](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData) object, append your image to it, and use a ajax call similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax) to post your data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the answer code.

**At client side**

```
function covertImage() {
var image = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/png");
sendMessage(image);
}

//Sending image data to server
function sendMessage(image){
   var msg = JSON.stringify(image);
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open('POST', true);
   xhr.send(msg);
   alert('file is saved');
}
```

**At Server Side**

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    var post='';
    if (request.method == 'POST') {
        var body = '';
        request.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
        });
        request.on('end', function () {
//-------------parsing data from json to string-------------------------
            post = JSON.parse(body);
            var data = post.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
            var buf = Buffer.from(data, 'base64');
            writeFileToSystem(buf);
        });
    }

//----------saving image to server side folder------------------
    function writeFileToSystem(buf)
    {
        fs.writeFile("images/image.png", buf, function(err) {
            console.log("The file was saved!");
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the DataURL is a string with the content-type and (generally) a base64-encoded string of the data which looks something like this:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQ...9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD/AD/6AP/Z
```

So there are a two things you can do with this:

1. You can decide to parse it by the client side and send the parsed result to your nodejs server with an [xhr request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)
2. You can send the string immediately with an [xhr request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) parsing it on your server side with something like [data-url-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-data-url)

Hope this helps getting you in the right direction