# React/node => image display not allowed to load local ressource

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm on a react/node website project. Pretty simple website with a crud.
My crud worked but my pictures doesn't appears (they are upload on a folder public/uploads/news/ and their path is save in mongoDb) For my news I can see the title, message, date but the picture is broken and I've only the alt.
When I go to the console and go on the element, the patch is OK "c:/users/......... /public/uploads/news/nameofmypicture.jpg".
I just got an error message "not allowed to load local resources"

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { dateParser, isEmpty } from "../../../general/utils/Utils";
import { updateNews } from "../../../../store/actions/news.actions";
import DeleteCard from "./DeleteCard";
import Loader from "../../../general/utils/Loading";

const Card = ({ news }) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [isUpdated, setIsUpdated] = useState(false);
    const [textUpdate, setTextUpdate] = useState(null);
    const newsData = useSelector((state) => state.newsReducer);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const updateItem = () => {
        if (textUpdate) {
            dispatch(updateNews(news._id, textUpdate));
        }
        setIsUpdated(false);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        !isEmpty(newsData[0]) && setIsLoading(false);
    }, [newsData]);

    return (
        <li className="card-container" key={news._id}>
            {isLoading ? (
                <Loader />
            ) : (
                <>
                    <div className="card-right">
                        <div className="card-header">
                        {isUpdated === false && <h3>{news.title}</h3>}
                        {isUpdated && (
                            <div className="update-title">
                                <textarea
                                    defaultValue={news.title}
                                    onChange={(e) => setTextUpdate(e.target.value)}
                                />
                            </div>
                        )}
                            <span>{dateParser(news.createdAt)}</span>
                        </div>
                        {isUpdated === false && <p>{news.message}</p>}
                        {isUpdated && (
                            <div className="update-post">
                                <textarea
                                    defaultValue={news.message}
                                    onChange={(e) => setTextUpdate(e.target.value)}
                                />
                                <div className="button-container">
                                    <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={updateItem}>
                                        Valider modification
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )}
                        {news.picture && (
                            <img src={news.picture} alt="card-pic" className="card-pic" />
                        )}
                        {news.video && (
                            <iframe
                                width="500"
                                height="300"
                                src={news.video}
                                frameBorder="0"
                                allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                                allowFullScreen
                                title={news._id}
                            ></iframe>
                        )}
                        <div className="button-container">
                            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() => setIsUpdated(!isUpdated)}>Edit</button>
                            <DeleteCard id={news._id} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </>
            )}
        </li>
    );
};

export default Card;
```

If someone wants the full code
https://github.com/macath/AJC-modelism
If you have more questions, ask me. I'm on this problem since 4 days, I really don't understand why it's don't work.
I specify that this project will be put online so I need a valid solution on a server and not only local

Ps : sorry for my English I'm French

Comment: The images cannot have absolute paths to your file system...They need to be served by the Web Server and need to have URLs to identify and load them

Answer (score 0):

please check this answer

[How to upload, display and save images using node.js and express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772394/how-to-upload-display-and-save-images-using-node-js-and-express)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Rolland Costomarob & @Siddharth Seth
I think the problem is that, i use multer to upload my pictures and i think i don't use it correctly.

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const newsController = require('../controllers/news.controller');

const multer = require('multer');
const imageStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, './client/public/uploads/')
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
        cb(null, 'file-' + uniqueSuffix + '.jpg')
    }
});
const upload = multer({
    limits: {
        fileSize: 10000000
    },
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg') {
          cb(null, true);
        }
        else {
          cb(new multer.MulterError('mauvais format de document'));
        }
      },
    storage: imageStorage
});

router.get('/', newsController.readNews);
router.post('/', upload.single('file'), newsController.createNews);
router.put('/:id', newsController.updateNews);
router.delete('/:id', newsController.deleteNews);

module.exports = router;
```

If you have the solution, you just save my life

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solve. In my news.controller i replace

```
picture: req.file.path
```

by

```
picture: req.file.filename
```

In my card.js i replace

```
img src={news.picture}
```

by

```
<img src={`${window.location.origin}/uploads/${news.picture}`}
```

thanks for your help